Martial arts film about female protagonists fighting an evil warlord

It's a Kung fu action movie;
Girls fight an evil warlord/spy;
Each girl has her name posted in the movie with a kind of background about her;
A ninja weapon finds a way to recruit them together; 
First scene involves a blonde girl who is like a pro wrestler/Kung Fu Kickboxer on a boat talking to her dad on the phone;
Possibly filmed between 2001 and 2015.


Sounds like DOA: Dead or Alive from 2006.

A number of fighters are invited to DOA, an invitational martial arts contest. They travel to the tournament island by plane, until they have to jump out mid-flight with parachutes, and then have until sundown to reach the main island to be entered into the tournament. Fighters are then pooled against one another in a knock-out style tournament, with the loser of a battle sent home, and the winner progressing to the subsequent round. The plot revolves around four female fighters who begin as rivals, but subsequently find themselves teaming up against another force.


The first scene (after an intro scene) shows one of the girls,  a blonde pro wrestler, on a boat talking to her father on the phone;
They're all introduced with a freeze frame and background information;
They're all invited to the tournament with a weapon (a flying shuriken);
They fight a main bad guy (Donovan) who has an evil plan.

Here's the trailer:




And that sounds almost exactly like Mortal Kombat hmmmm

...Only with more bikinis. :/

Staying true to the source material after all :)

Lol, yep, what a movie. I didn't remember the girl calling her father scene. All my memories were filled by the "girl acrobatics dressing up" scene: http://bit.ly/1MM9cRX

I believe you are looking for "So Close", a film originally titled "Xi yang tian shi" filmed in Singapore in 2002. Its aesthetics were very nice by that genre's standards at that time.

